# why can't nodejs execute /dev/stdin

Tags: node.js, shell

```bash
printf 'console.log(1)' | node /dev/stdin
```

gives

```
node:fs:453
    return binding.readFileUtf8(path, stringToFlags(options.flag));
                   ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/proc/2513530/fd/pipe:[611889]'
```

I tried python, tcc, all works.

for example:

```bash
printf 'print("hi")' | python /dev/stdin
printf 'int main(){ puts("111");return 0;}' | tcc -run /dev/stdin
```